# How would I go about creating a php script to execute a shell command to write text to another php file?

Tags: php, linux, shell, execute, shell-exec

How would I go about creating a php script to execute a shell command to write text to another php file? and not have any sudo problems. I have this so far.

```
<?php
include("inc/config.php");
$command = "sed -i '$ a\this is line 2 without redirection' admin.php";
$command1 = "cat admin.php";
$output = shell_exec($command);
$output1 = shell_exec($command1);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";
?>
```

and I used chown wwwdata and chmod 777

Comment: don't know what you mean, but shell_exec("bash commands to want to use"); will do the job

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you be using shell commands, because in most cases `fopen()` - `fwrite` - `fclose` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs to run under an account that has permissions to do everything you need to do.  It's that simple.

Comment: Agreed, also make sure that `shell_exec` is not a [disabled function](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/) as specified in your php.ini file.  With some shared hosting providers, it is.